# using sd to find outliers

Tags: r, function, outliers

I am trying to find values 3sd away from the mean. I have written below function but I am getting error saying: iif (result > sds) print(outlier) :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

My data has NA values so the function is trying to analyse the NA values how do I say na.rm=TRUE kind of command in the function?

```
findingoutlier<- function (data, cutoff=3, na.rm=TRUE){
  sd <- sd(data)
  mean <- mean(data)
  sds <- mean + (sd * cutoff)
  result <- lapply(data, sd)
  outlier <- if (result > sds)
    print (outlier)
}
```

Comment: Change `mean(data)` to `mean(data, na.rm = na.rm)` and `sd(data)` to `sd(data, na.rm = na.rm)` . Your function has some other errors too though. You could just find the means and sd then do `return(data[data < mean - cutoff * sd | data > mean + cutoff * sd])` . This would be better than printing the result too.

Comment: Consider having your function just return a value, and not induce a side effect (printing to console).